# "CA 1852 Type X can be sealed because it has no subtypes in its containing assembly and is not externally visible" error while compiling

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I tried to compile a .NET app I got from GitHub and got a
`"CA 1852 Type X can be sealed because it has no subtypes in its containing assembly and is not externally visible"` error. This seems to be a code style error instead of a real error.

To try to suppress it, I added the 1852 line to the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1852</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

plus this to the .editorconfig file:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CS1852.severity = none
```

'dotnet_diagnostic' might be incorrect. Both didn't work.

So what worked was adding this above the error line:

```
#pragma warning disable CA1852
```

My question is what triggered this type of error to show up? .editorconfig doesn't have anything for 1852, unless it's a computer wide setting on my machine or something?

Also, how do I suppress it for the whole solution or project?

Comment: Firstly, it's not an error. The fact that you're supressing a warning should tell you that. Warnings are not errors. Errors prevent code compiling. Warnings are just information about things that could become issues in particular scenarios

Comment: Secondly, the warning itself tells you exactly why it has been raised. You have a type that is not inherited within its assembly and is not exposed outside its assembly. Is there an intention to inherit it at some stage in the future? If not, why not declare it `sealed`? That is an explicit statement that the type is not to be inherited. Did you think to read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1852)?

Comment: BTW, that documentation says that this warning is new in .NET 7, so you may not have seen it before with similar code in earlier versions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It's a warning being treated as an error and causing a compile error. Like I said in the post, it's not clear where this warning is being set as an error. Like I said also in the post, it's an app downloaded from Github. It's not sealed there and it seems to be working for the author and the repo has over 3k stars. The project is not targeting .NET 7.0.
With over 3k stars, I need to know why it's working for everyone else and not myself.
I aware of what a warning and I wouldn't have posted this question if it was just a warning.

Comment: It was the WarningsAsErrors setting which @kit was able to mention. I hinted in my post about some kind of setting that's probably causing and I didn't know which one it was. You didn't either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CA1852](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1852) is not a compiler error or warning. It is a [static code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview?tabs=net-7) warning where the analysis is done by "Rosyln". If it is actually preventing you from compiling code, then you have `WarningsAsErrors` turned on.

Regardless, you can follow the advice or [suppress the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings). All of @jmcilhinney's comments are correct and relevant, and the fact that the warning is new is likely the trigger.

To my knowledge, there is no built-in global way to suppress a warning solution wide. That said, you can effect the same result by including a "standard" bit of configuration stored in a separate file. It's still not technically global because each `.csproj` will need to be modified to import the settings.

To do that, create a file such as `CommonStuff.xml` with

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <NoWarn>1852</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

in it. Then modify each of your `.csproj` to include this file:

```xml
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\CommonStuff.xml" />
```

In the above, I chose `SolutionDir` as that is probably the best place to add this file and reference it from all the projects. Other paths can be used; see [Common macros...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170) in the Microsoft documentation. The other good choice would be `ProjectDir` if that's the level of granularity you need.

Comment: See my replies to @jmcilhinney. I am aware it's a warning but it was treated like an error and I didn't know where this was set.

This is a Github repo that seems to be used by thousands of users so I was surprised that I was getting it and no one else since no one was complaining about it.

It was WarningsAsErrors set to true in the Directory.Build.props file.